# Nslookup cannot find name servers without www

Tags: nslookup

Our site is responding to nslookup if it is fully written.

`nslookup www.example.com` - it responds and shows name servers.

But if we write without www, 
 like `nslookup example.com` - it cannot find name servers.

What may be the problem?

I have these records:

```
@ IN NS ns1.example.com. 
localhost.example.com. IN A 127.0.0.1
ns1.example.com. IN A ip_add_of_www
```

What else should I add?

Answer (score 1):

DNS is similar to a database of names.

If you do not put there a record, it won't answer to it when being consulted /read.

So, if you have not created two A records, and only created www.example.com, it will only give an address to www.example.com

As CNAMEs pointing to  a domain are not allowed per DNS rfcs/"papers", you have to define not an alias, but an address.

Using bind syntax, where @ is shorthand for your domain:

```
@       IN A   192.0.2.1
```

Where 192.0.2.0 is the same address of the A RR attributed to www.

As in:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     startech60serve root.startech60serve.com (
    2018110201  ;Serial
    3600        ;Refresh
    1800        ;Retry
    604800      ;Expire
    86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

 IN  NS      x.x.x.x

 www      IN A 192.0.2.1
 @        IN A 192.0.2.1
```

After changing, you need to restart increase the serial.

After increasing, you either restart the service or do a

```
rndc reload
```

Comment: I have these records:   @     IN     NS   ns1.example.com. ,  localhost.example.com.  IN A 127.0.0.1, ns1.example.com. IN A ip_add_of_www      What else should I add? Nslookup responds only to www.example.com

Comment: Add it before or after that IN A,. I prefer it before.

Comment: can you write fully please? What line should I add?

Comment: The line is in the answer. I cannot add your data as mobile /phone bound for now

Comment: Now that Cloudflare is running an active (and reasonably popular) DNS server on 1.1.1.1, using that as a random IP in examples is risky. Better use something from 192.0.2.0/24, 198.51.100.0/24 or 203.0.113.0/24 (IP ranges reserved for examples and documentation).

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I tried adding that line before A record, did not work. I added this: example.com IN A ip_add_of_my_www

Comment: Add _what M. Ribeiro actually wrote_ instead.

Comment: @JdeBP, what exactly in my case?

Comment: @muru Thanks, well pointed out.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, why should I increase serial? is it possible doing without increasing serial?